# Why does the derived clone() method return a reference?

Tags: rust

Deriving the `Clone` trait for a struct containing a reference to object of generic type (Unless it has `Clone` bound. In that case cloning work as expected) will generate `clone()` method which returns a reference to object but not a new object.

I have the code:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct A<'a, T: 'a>{
    ref_generic: &'a T
}

fn test_call<'a, T: 'a>(a: &A<'a, T>)->A<'a, T>{
    a.clone()
}
```

Which will cause an error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:15:5
   |
14 | fn test_call<'a, T: 'a>(a: &A<'a, T>)->A<'a, T>{
   |                                        -------- expected `A<'a, T>` because of return type
15 |     a.clone()
   |     ^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `A`, found &A<'_, T>
   |
   = note: expected type `A<'a, T>`
              found type `&A<'_, T>`
```

Why does derive behave this way?

Following manual implementation allow to avoid this obstacle but unpleasant.

```
impl<'a, T: 'a> Clone for A<'a, T>{
    fn clone(&self)->Self{
        A{ref_generic: self.ref_generic}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are not calling `A::clone()`. You are calling `&A::clone()`, i.e. you are cloning the reference, not the object.

The compiler would actually prefer to call `A::clone()`, because the argument matches more precisely (`Clone::clone` takes a `&self`, so the single ref matches exactly, instead of requiring auto-ref for the call to the reference clone), but it can't. (You can see that by looking at the error message you get when you try to do `(*a).clone()` instead.) This is because the auto-derived `Clone` naively implements it as:

```
impl <'a, T: Clone + 'a> Clone for A<'a, T> {
  fn clone(&self) -> Self { Self { ref_generic: self.ref_generic } }
}
```

Note the `Clone` bound on `T`. That bound is not necessary, but the auto-derivation still requires it. This is [bug #26925](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26925).

Your `test_call` function does not have a bound on `T`, which means that the derived `Clone` impl for `A` is not available, so the compiler falls back to the only `Clone` impl it can call, which is the one for `&A`.

Comment: This means that if you replace `struct A<'a, T: 'a>` with `struct A<'a, T: Clone + 'a>` and `fn test_call<'a, T: 'a>` with `fn test_call<'a, T: Clone + 'a>`, your example will work.